# How to format keyboard keys in posts?

Tags: support, markdown

Is there a way to format (style) keyboard keys like CTRL?

Comment: Depending on the site, you can use: `<kbd>KEY</kbd>`

Comment: @Louis Thx alot!

Comment: @pc-shooter You're welcome. Yes, this is the right place but the way you initially put it, I had to do a double take before I figured you were talking about how to style text in *posts*. At first, it looked like a post from someone who meant to ask a question on the main site but posted to Meta by mistake.

Comment: @Louis The "markdown" Part was the lack of knowledge ;-) So everything from MarkDown can be uesd then?

Comment: @pc-shooter you probably want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help - that details all the markdown and inline HTML supported for SO

Comment: This isn't supported by Markdown, so while Louis is technically correct, it is really not applicable to this question. You have to fall back to the supported subset of HTML tags.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the HTML `<kbd>` tag:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>

```
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>
```

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work in comments, only answers/questions.